# HtmlUnit SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone

Tags: java, security, warnings, htmlunit

When I use HtmlUnit library and try to get html anchor, try to click it then I get this message:

> SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your
>   password and do not share it with anyone

I tried all solutions for turn off warning of javascript, all of them are field :(

Please help me.

Comment: Please provide the URL so others can check

Comment: "http://www.mobihall.com/samsung-galaxy-s4-mobile-28.html?m=0"

there is link for 'read more' of comments >> I'm developing crawler for get reviews .. and I need to click this link multiple to get all reviews not only last 5 comments .....

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wait for AJAX as hinted [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork)

With latest version, the below gives even more comments.

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://mobihall.com/samsung-galaxy-s4-mobile-28.html?m=0");
    HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getFirstByXPath("//a[@class='load_more']");
    anchor.click();
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10_000);
    System.out.println(page.asXml());
}
```

Comment: look at my code:
page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.mobihall.com/samsung-galaxy-s4-mobile-28.html?m=0");
                  
MoreAnchor = page1.getFirstByXPath("//a[@class='load_more']"); 
                   while(MoreAnchor != null)
                   { 
                        page1 = MoreAnchor.click(); 
                        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
                        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000); 
                        MoreAnchor = page1.getFirstByXPath("//a[@class='load_more']");
                   }

Comment: I did all suggestions in stackoverflow to turn off warning.. last result the problems solved but not completly.. sometimes get this warning...

Comment: Your commnent example is incomplete, besides pagePage() needs "http" at the beginning. Please edit your question, to include the full scenario, and make sure you use latest version 2.16.

Comment: Use CHROME, it works with me without blocking exceptions, the warning messages can be ignored

Comment: I already use chrome .. and it also wrok for me .. but not always !!
most times i get this warning instead of page result !!
How I could ignore this warning ......

Comment: hi @lady, pay attention to yourwebClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStarting**Before**(10000) values should be like 200 or 100 ms.. low values that capture tasks that will be executed, its not the value of amout time wait like _waitForBackgroundJavaScript_ also try Thread.sleep(2000)(seconds) before manipulating your landing page.

Comment: Thank u .. I benefit from ur advice.. until now I tried several times and it's working correctly .. I hope the prolem solved !!